# How to integrate $e^{\sqrt{2x}}$?

Tags: integration

I think this problem requires integration by substitution and integration by parts, but I seem to get stuck each time I try to solve it. And I'm not sure whether '$u$' should be equal to $\sqrt{2}$ or $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x}$.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Setting $t=\sqrt{2x}$, we get $x=\frac{t^2}{2}$ and $dx=tdt$ we get the integral $\int te^{t}dt$ in a few minutes.

I will post the solution: setting $u=t$ and $v'=e^{t}$, we obtain $u'=1$ and $v=e^{t}$. Thus we have $\int te^{t}dt=te^{t}-e^{t}+C$.

Comment: Maybe mention explicitly that you're using integration by parts? The OP sounds inexperienced with these types of problems, and could use as much guidance as possible.

Comment: I'm aware, I'm not that incompetent haha